# Restructuring of Database/Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have a database that has these tables

```
Car --> Has Dealerships --> Has Demographic --> Has Revenue
```

Later after launch the client says they want the car to have model types and each model should have a dealership

So my structure becomes

```
Car --> Has Model --> Has Dealerships --> has Demographic --> Has Revenue
```

How would I migrate to the second database structure? I would need to sever foreign keys between the `Car` and `Dealership` for this to work. Would I just take a snapshot of the old database and write a wrapper in the context that knows how to deal with it?

Comment: Do you need to do this on a live system without loss of data, or is this something that can be done while no one is looking? It is common to use temporary columns and/or tables to hold the old and new id's while fixing up the foreign keys.

Comment: Why in the world does this have 4 upvotes? What attempt has been made on OP's side?

Comment: If `-->` is supposed to denote a one-to-many relationship, then perhaps it would be more accurate to write `Model --> Has Cars`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is it should be `Model --> Has Cars`, not `Car --> Has Model`. That would seem to me a more consistent use of the `-->` designation.

So, the correct final relationship chain would probably look something like this:

```
Model --> Has Cars
      --> Has Dealerships --> Has Demographic --> Has Revenue
```

I would imagine the following sequence of actions:

1. Create and populate the `Models` table. Your schema at this point:

   ```
   Model

   Car --> Has Dealerships --> Has Demographic --> Has Revenue
   ```
2. Add a `ModelID` column to `Cars` and populate it with the correct `Models` references based on your business requirements. It'll give you the following result:

   ```
   Model --> Has Cars --> Has Dealerships --> Has Demographic --> Has Revenue
   ```
3. Add a `ModelID` reference to `Dealerships`, populate it by joining `Dealerships` to `Cars` using the current relationship. You will end up having double relationship between `Dealerships` and `Models`, direct and through `Cars`, like this:

   ```
   Model      -->     Has Dealerships --> Has Demographic --> Has Revenue
       \               /
        \-> Has Cars -/
   ```
4. Drop the `Cars --> Dealership` foreign key, drop the `Dealerships.CarID` reference column. This will be your final result:

   ```
   Model --> Has Dealerships --> Has Demographic --> Has Revenue
       \
        \--> Has Cars
   ```